# Script to copy files with desired name

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've got a problem i'm facing for 6-7 hours and i can't overcome it , that's why i'm asking for your help.I need to create a bash script that accesses a folder and renames all the files from it with a new name followed by a number that represents  alalphabetic hierachy and a new extension.

**The parameters are in this order:

(The new name , the new extension , and the folder where i'm searching).

As an example : ./rename.sh work .txt Documents

Let's say that initially the document (Documents) contained :

a.txt

b.txt

c.txt

Therefore , afer running the script the document will containt the following:
work01.txt(from a.txt)

work02.txt(from b.txt)

work03.txt(from c.txt)**

The problem is that somehow i'm duplicating the files and i'm creating a big mess.
Here is the script (rename.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$3" ]
   then
    echo "No argumets supplied"
   else
    mic="0"
    i="1"
    max="9"
    for file in `ls $3 | sort -V`; do
        if ( test $i -le 9)
          then
            cp $3/$file $3/$1$mic$i.$2
            rm -r $3/$file
          else
            if ( test $i -ge 9 )
              then          
                cp $3/$file $3/$1$i.$2
                rm -r $3/$file
                fi
          fi
        i=$((i+1))  
    done
    echo "$max"
fi
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I'd suggest using the bash shell's builtin `printf` to construct the newname with suitable zero-padded format (rather than trying to hack together something based on different variables for different digits) e.g. `printf -v newname 'work%02d.txt' $((i++))`

Comment: @steeldriver for single digit numbers a 0 is added before them ,that's all.For numbers with more than 2 digits there is nothing more to be done.If i wasnt't explicit enough you can ask me questions about things i've forgot to mention.

Comment: Well, are your files *really* called a.txt, b.txt etc or is that just meant to illustrate an ordering? What do you want to happen if a file is missing e.g. if h.txt doesn't exist, should i.txt become work08.txt or still be renamed to work09.txt regardless?

Comment: @steeldriver i.txt should become work08.txt

Comment: this is still unsolved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your files are named a.txt, b.txt and so on, then the default collation order should allow you to do a simple filename glob expansion, rather than needing to explicitly version-sort the files. So I'd suggest doing something more like

```
i=1

cd "$dir"
for old in *."$ext"; do 
  printf -v new '%s%02d.%s' "$newbase" $((i++)) "$ext"
  echo mv "$old" "$new"
done
```

after assigning `newbase="$1"`, `ext="$2"`, `dir="$3"` (with suitable existence checks of course). Play with it and remove the `echo` once the printed output looks correct.

Comment: Forr some reason they are not modified accordingly. a.txt won't become thenewname01.x etc. I don't know the reason. I think i must read them sorted..but i don't know how to do that. The files in the folder are something like image1.pdf image2.pdf image3.pdf etc.

Comment: The files from the folder might have a diffrent extension than the ones that are going to be created. So i don't think that "for" will work.

Comment: That's why I asked if your files were *really* called a.txt, b.txt and so on